# get data from a variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the variable below:

```
var a = {"id": 0, "Nodeid": 1234, "title":"abc"};
```

I want to extract Nodeid value from the above and store in a different variable.
Required output is:

```
var x = 1234;
```

Comment: This is very basics, I suggest you to read some tutorials to learn JavaScript better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript.

Comment: This is not an angularjs problem

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
var x = a["Nodeid"];
```

or

```
var x = a.Nodeid;
```

`a` is just an object, and `Nodeid` is one of its properties, which you can access in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var a, x;

a = {
  id: 0,
  Nodeid: 1234,
  title: 'abc'
};

x = a.Nodeid;
```

Becouse 'a' is object. a['Nodeid'] was found too, but on the first look say that 'a' is array

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Code-only answers are liable to be deleted - this one is [in a queue to be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10430854) right now.